# What does the notation ${ $.index } refer to in XML files

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent

I've recently started hoping on the Magento2 train. And I'm quite puzzled by some of the aspects of building dataGrids.

One of which is a weird syntax I came across on answers here or on tutorials on the web.
For example, there's a bit that tells Magento how to store Bookmark values (as I understand it).

```
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">jobs_department_listing.jobs_department_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
</item>
```

I really don't understand this notation: **columns.${ $.index }**. Is looks like JS to me, definitely not XML, but I don't know where it's coming from, nor where to look for it, as it's not defined anywhere in the .xsd either.

Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: From  what I found, its only used in UI files. It is used to be replaced with "Real" data when rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am right your piece of code comes from **columns definition**.
It is a **variable notation** that will be **replaced with actual values** during the grid rendering procedure.

**Theory:**

`${ ... }` means: It is a variable.

`${ $.something }` means: The property "something" of current object (in your example the **object is a row**).

**In short:**

`${ $.index }` means: "The current column index".

`${ $.storageConfig.root}`: It is referring to `root` property of current `storageConfig` that you previously defined as `${ $.index }`. So, at the end it should take the same value as `${ $.index }` if I am right.

**UPDATE:**

Look at `vendor/magento/magento2-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/data-storage.js`.

Replacement is made in `template.js` file in `vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/utils/template.js`.

You can find further information in the very first lines of that js file:

```
var tmplSettings = _.templateSettings,
        interpolate = /\$\{([\s\S]+?)\}/g,
        opener = '${',
        template,
        hasStringTmpls;
```

And around line 35 you can see `$` definition:

```
        /**
         * Evaluates template string using ES6 templates.
         *
         * @param {String} tmpl - Template string.
         * @param {Object} $ - Data object used in a template.
         * @returns {String} Compiled template.
         */
        template = function (tmpl, $) {
            return eval('`' + tmpl + '`');
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But is there any mean to be sure? What processes these XML nodes?

Comment: Updated my post with more information.

Comment: I don't get it, is something sending `${ $.index }` to the templates, which get read and replaced in JS?

Comment: This is how Magento UI components work. They are XML configured ans JS rendered.